# Crash server node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm, axios

Good morning,
i'm asking for your help for my project. I want to display rainbow six stats  since this api: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rainbowsix-api-node

I created a server node and express, a react's front. My problem: my node server crash stops 3 time out of 5, he is not stable and and I noticed that the r6 server npm solicited works well during off-peak hours.
I run the server with npm start but when i update my react app the server often stops and displays this

after several searches, I do not understand where the problem may come from ; thanks for your help !

Console return this:

```html
Server is listening on port 5000
undefined:1
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! back@1.0.0 start: `node index`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the back@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

my back's code:

```js
const RainbowSixApi = require('rainbowsix-api-node');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const statsRouter = require('./routes/stats');
const R6 = new RainbowSixApi();

//let username = '<username here>';
let platform = 'ps4';

app.get('/api/stats/:username', (req, res) => {
  const username = req.params.username;

R6.stats(username, platform).then(response => {
    res.send(response);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  });
});


app.use('/api/stats', statsRouter)

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error('Erreur')
  }
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

My React Code

```js
class Cards extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      statsArray: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const urls =
    [
      '/api/stats/username1',
      '/api/stats/username2',
      '/api/stats/username3',
      '/api/stats/username4',
      '/api/stats/username5',
    ]

    let promiseArray = urls.map(url => axios.get(url).then(response => response.data).catch(error => { console.error(error) }));

    Promise.all(promiseArray)
      .then(statsArray => this.setState({ statsArray }))
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not your problem. This is a problem of the `'rainbowsix-api-node'` code.

Because in peak hours instead of returning the JSON value it is returning a HTML page(most probably an error page).

Saw the code in GitHub, this is where the error is generating.

```
request.get(endpoint, (error, response, body) => {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == '200') {
        return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
    } else {
        return reject(JSON.parse(body));
    }
})
```

Now, what you can do is just `try..catch` it.

```
app.get('/api/stats/:username', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.params.username;
    try{
        R6.stats(username, platform).then(response => {
            res.send(response);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        });
    }catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    };
});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for that answer!

I've the files of github, do you thin this problem can be fixed if i modifie the main.js file?

Comment: As I said you can add the `try..catch` block as I wrote above. it will fix your problem.